# Why does my ViewController get modally presented two times in a row after a single call to present(_:animated:completion:) method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

When I try to modally present a view controller from the 4th tab of my TabBarController, which is a TableViewController embedded in a NavigationViewController, it gets presented two times in a row.
Actual method `present(_:animated:completion:)` gets called two times in a row, when it should happen only one time.

This is how I call the method from the `UITableViewController`. Now because I was getting an "Attempt to present vc whose view is not in the window hierarchy" warning I tried this workaround and I don't get that warning anymore, but now I have this problem.

```
((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarViewController)?.selectedViewController as? NavigationPodesavanjaViewController)?.visibleViewController?.present(Egg, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is all the content from the view controller that gets presented. Its just like a dummy content for now, with a back button:

```
import UIKit

class EasterEggViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.backgroundColor = ConstantsClass.ljubicastaBoja

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "operator-ikonica"))
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)

    let backButton = UIButton()
    view.addSubview(backButton)

    backButton.setTitle("Nazad", for: .normal)
    backButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 20)
    backButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissAction), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func dismissAction() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

The method present gets called in a handler for a long press gesture.
//NOTE: When i changed long press to tap, it worked as it should, when I changed it back, it again got presented two times.

This is part of the code from viewDidLoad:

```
    let longPressEgg = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    longPressEgg.addTarget(self, action: #selector(easterEggScreenPresent))
    easterEgg.addGestureRecognizer(longPressEgg)
```

And this is the handler:

```
 @objc func easterEggScreenPresent(){

    let Egg = EasterEggViewController()
    ((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarViewController)?.selectedViewController as? NavigationPodesavanjaViewController)?.visibleViewController?.present(Egg, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no second present call at some other place?

Comment: Is this a root viewController for the tabBar? Or is it a controller that gets presented on the 4th tab after a push?

Comment: @AndréSlotta Yes, this same method, on the same line, gets called two times.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla This is called on the 4th tab of the TabBarViewController.

Comment: I understood that. But that was not what I meant. Are you sure that there is no other call of the present method at some other part of your code? And what is `Egg` btw?

Comment: @AndréSlotta Yes, when I comment this method out, no presentation will happen. But if I leave it, the presentation happens twice, and the line this method is on gets executed twice.

Comment: Can you please show some code of the view controller class that gets presented? And where exactly do you call this line from your question? Some more context would help.

Comment: Can you please add a little more context for the code? It is very difficult to understand the question with a single line of code.

Comment: I guess you call `present` in `viewDidLoad` or something. At that time the view controller's view is - as the warning states - not yet in the view hierarchy. Move the `present` call to `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: @AndréSlotta  Update: I just changed the recognizer from long press to tap, and it gets presented only once. When I changed the recognizer back to long press it again gets presented two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gets called multiple times with different states. In your case you should present the view controller when the gesture begins. Change your `easterEggScreenPresent` to the following:

```
@objc func easterEggScreenPresent(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.state == .began else { return }

    let egg = EasterEggViewController()
    ((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarViewController)?.selectedViewController as? NavigationPodesavanjaViewController)?.visibleViewController?.present(egg, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```